# Emacs and Trac Integration

Tags: emacs, trac

Is there a way to integrate Trac and Emacs?
e.g. edit Wiki pages in org mode, edit and manage tickets from within emacs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [Trac Wiki page editing mode for Emacs](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/EmacsWikiEditScript). It is supposed to ease editing Trac Wiki pages but also help with diffing, merging, highlighting and completion.

It is also mentioned at [the EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/trac_editor) and in [a blog post](http://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/emacs-and-personal-trac-wiki/).

Answer (score 0):

Personally for ticket management I use a dirty script in org-babel-python that would retrieve the list of tickets inline, into my org page:

```
#+begin_src python :results output
base_url = "http://your.trac.site.url"
ticket_list_url = "http://your.trac.site/query?..."
headers = {"Cookie": "trac_form_token=token-from-browser-session; trac_auth=your-auth-from-browser-session"}

import requests
tasks_html = requests.get(ticket_list_url, headers=headers)

from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MyHtmlParser(HTMLParser):
  in_link = False
  link_href = None

  def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    attrs = dict(attrs)
    if tag == "a" and attrs["href"].startswith("/ticket"):
      self.in_link = True
      self.link_href = attrs["href"]
    else:
      self.in_link = False

  def handle_data(self, data):
    data = data.strip()
    if self.in_link and data and not data.startswith("#"):
      ticket_num = self.link_href[8:]
      print "*** #" + ticket_num + " [[" + base_url + self.link_href + "][" + data + "]]"

MyHtmlParser().feed(tasks_html.text)

#+end_src
```

The script requires `pip install requests` plus org-babel with python enabled. Plus you need to set your `*_url` & set auth headers from your browser session.

Org-babel scripts can be run with `C-c C-c`

Just in case someone needs a dirty solution for listing tickets from trac in an org page..